# shell script if statement trouble

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to set up a hardware mute button for my notebook running chrunchbang linux,
I've got the key event handling working and pointing to a script like this :

```
curvol=$(amixer get Master | grep 'off')
if ["$curvol" != ""]
then
amixer set Master unmute 
else
amixer set Master mute
fi
```

what happens is on pressing the button assigned, it will unmute if muted; but it won't mute if it isn't already muted.

I think the problem is in the if statement where I check for output from the command; it seems to be always doing the unmute, regardless of whether the if returns true or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$curvol` is what you expect?

Comment: Include spaces around the `[` command/operator and the `]` token

Comment: I added an echo, it seems as if it's not using the grep, and is just returning the full output of amixer get Master

Comment: adding spaces seems to have worked, I now feel rather silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is the name of a command (or shell builtin, sometimes).  You need a space after it for it to work:

```
if [ "$curvol" != "" ]
```

Comment: Don't feel silly - it's a common problem brought on by the fact that `[` used to be a synonym for the `test` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the return value of grep:

```
amixer get Master | grep 'off' &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
  amixer set Master unmute 
else
  amixer set Master mute
fi
```

Comment: Even simpler: use `if amixer get Master | grep -q 'off'; then`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it would be a lot simpler to just write:

```
amixer set Master ${curvol:+un}mute
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if test -n "$curvol"; then
  amixer set Master unmute
else
  amixer set Master mute
fi
```

but much less wordy.  Also, note that by using `test` instead of `[`, the syntax error becomes much more difficult to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Python. I added a BASH function to toggle the mute state.
Stick it in ~/.bashrc

I'm currently using a laptop, so, I don't have multiple sound cards.
I'm not doing any error checking.

See /usr/share/doc/python-alsaaudio/examples/mixertest.py
for more sample code.

```
# toggle Master mute                                            
function tm(){
python -c "                                                     
import alsaaudio                                                

mixerObj = alsaaudio.Mixer()                                    
currentMute = mixerObj.getmute()[0]                             
newMute = not currentMute                                       
mixerObj.setmute(newMute)                                       
"
}
```